# Send email using AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I want to send email via Gmail (using AutoIt) but I do not know how to enable TLS. My code returns an error (`4`):

```
#include <Inet.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#Include<file.au3>

Local $sSMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com";
Local $sFromName    = "Emeka";
Local $sFromAddress = "e.iwuagwung@gmail.com";
Local $sToAddress   = "e.iwuagwung@gmail.com";
Local $sSubject     = "AuToIT";
Local $aBody[1]     = "Test ";

Local $iResponse    = _INetSmtpMail($sSMTPServer, $sFromName, $sFromAddress,$sToAddress, $sSubject, $aBody)
Local $iErr         = @error

If $iResponse = 1 Then

    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Success!", "Mail sent")

Else

    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Error!", "Mail failed with error code " & $iErr)

EndIf
```

Why is my email not being sent?

Comment: In the function it is hard coded to connect to port 25, however this is not allowed by the google servers. You'l have to rewrite the `_INetSmtpMail` function slightly to include TLS, not entirely sure how though.

Comment: One solution given is to use a different method entirely, using COM objects. [Here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/23860-smtp-mailer-that-supports-html-and-attachments/#comment-166575).

Comment: For reference, question asked on [AutoIt Forums](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/181415-error-4-auto-it-email/).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server

You need to check the google SMTP settings, I think.
I once made a mail sender and got some stupid error that is easily fixed. Check link above.